# How do I use VBA to check if row 2 contains the same string as row 1 then copy paste the row to another location?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check if row C3 has the same string as C2 then how do I have it then copy to something like  BC2?

So check the row above it, see if it has the same value as the current row and if it does, then copy the whole row to a new location.

Comment: What's the new location? You would also probably get better responses after reading [ask] and providing a [mcve].

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub checkRow()
Dim r As Range
Dim r2 As Range

Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
Set copyToRng = Application.InputBox("Please choose a the row you want to copy to: ", , , , , , , 8)

If rng1 = rng2 Then
    rng2.EntireRow.Copy (copyToRng.EntireRow)
End If

End Sub
```

The 2 cells that you are checking are hard coded right now. The range to copy to is input by the user. You could go about determining what cells to compare to each other, and what row to copy to a few different ways.